# How to access database in the running Docker Image

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose

Angular, Node.js, mongoose, mongo

On BE I reated a docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongo_db
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
volumes:
  data:
```

And this is my database/index.js

```
const db = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/User");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

db.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT, // mongodb://localhost:27017/playground
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  { useUnifiedTopology: true },
  { useCreateIndex: true }
)
  .then(() => console.log("connnected to db!"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

When I run "docker compose up" in terminal
I can see the created db, I can see that the image is running.
I open my Docker for Windows app, and see that there is my image.

Now I created a data input controller for User
In postman I can retrieve all entities from the User Table from the Image

My question is how to find that Table in on the image directly?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is your application also running in a container?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You stated that you can access your table, but you ask how you can find the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Power Shell Window

Display all running containers with: docker ps

Find your running container (in my case: "mongo_db")

Open the container in bash like this:

```
docker exec -it mongo_db bash 

mongo             // opens mongo

show dbs          // shows all available databases (default: admin, config, local)

use playground    // this is my (see database/index.js file above)

show collections  // displays my users Table

db.users.find().pretty()  // displays all entities from the table
```